# Cancel AsyncTask when internet connection is lost in the process of running

Tags: android, networking, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I am developing a news app which performs Async task, but during the running of the Async task if the internet connection is lost the app crashes. I tried solving the issue by Using a broadcast receiver and cancel the async task when connection is lost but the problem still persist. Below is my full activity source code.

```
public class News extends AppCompatActivity{

    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    GridView gridview;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    Toolbar mToolbar;

    static String NEWS = "news";
    static String ID = "id";
    static String PROFILE_PIC = "news_pic";


    DownloadNews downloader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news);

        IntentFilter filter = new    IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);        
        registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, filter);


        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.discoverGrid);

         downloader = new DownloadNews();



        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Couldn't refresh",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        else
        {

            downloader.execute();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  if ( downloader.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING ){
                      downloader.cancel(true);
                  linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Internet Connection is Down",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }
                  else if(downloader.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
                  linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                  }

              }
            }, 15000 );
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.news, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            return true;
        }


        else if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class DownloadNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            while(true){

                  if (isCancelled())  
                     break;
             }

            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            try {
                try {
                    jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                           .getJSONfromURL("http://www.example.com/app/news.php");
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }   


            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("news");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrieve JSON Objects
                    map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    map.put("profile_pic", jsonobject.getString("news_pic"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            adapter = new GridViewAdapter(News.this, arraylist);
            gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(){
            downloader.cancel(true);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    BroadcastReceiver networkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

            if(!noConnectivity) {
                    onConnectionFound();
            } else {
                    onConnectionLost();
            }
        }
    };


    public void onConnectionLost() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection lost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        downloader.cancel(true);

    }

    public void onConnectionFound() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(networkStateReceiver);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is broken.  Your while(true) loop is miswritten, its looping until you're canceled then trying to do a network request.  That's probably not what you want.  What you want to do is just remove that loop entirely (which may need further debugging after that).  If you really want to continually download the data over and over, you want a Thread and not an AsyncTask, and the body of your function should all be inside that while loop.